# Defining new types in Haskell - RPS game

Tags: haskell

I'm completely new to Haskell (and more generally to functional programming), so forgive me if this is really basic stuff. I'm reading Real World Haskell and I'm creating the RPS Game

---

```
data Move = Paper | Rock | Scissors
deriving (Eq, Show)

data Result =  Win | Draw | Lose   
deriving (Eq, Show)

-- function returns the move which beats the other move
beats :: Move -> Move -> Bool
beats Scissors Paper = True
beats Paper Rock     = True
beats Rock Scissors  = True
beats _ _            = False

-- instead I could use in the 2º line: loses_to = flip beats

loses_to :: Move -> Move -> Bool
loses_to Scissors Paper = False
loses_to Paper Rock     = False
loses_to Rock Scissors  = False
loses_to _ _            = True

-- find out what the score is for moves and return Win or Draw or Lose
score :: Move -> Move -> Result
score this_move opposing_move
 | this_move `beats` opposing_move    = Win
 | this_move `loses_to` opposing_move = Lose
 | otherwise                          = Draw
```

---

There are probably a lot smarter ways to create this code. But in the example it uses the two functions "beats" and "loses_to".
I'm stuck in creating a function called winners as follows:
A function called 'winners' that receives a list of moves and returns a list of the indexes of the winning moves.

```
winners :: [Move] -> ?
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Steve.

Comment: What's a winning move? All your predicates so far relate two moves to each other; none is about a single move.

Comment: Presumably you want to pit some of the moves in the list against others. But which? You can help by providing some desired example input-output pairs of the `winners` function.

Comment: Note that `loses_to /= flip beats`: `loses_to Rock Rock`, but not `beats Rock Rock`.

Comment: I think `loses_to` *should* be implemented as `flip beats`, but actually as written it is equivalent to `(not .) . beats`. This is more an error in the current implementation than in the statement that it could be implemented as `flip beats`.

Comment: (As an aside, I think it would be easier to define `score` directly via an `==` guard for draws and inlining the `beats` pattern matching for winners. Everything else, by process of elimination, would be losers.)